# Save the prediction output of Tensorflow model into hdfs file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, tensorflow, hdfs, distribution

I have a trained a tf model and I want to apply it to big dataset in hdfs which is about billion of samples. The main point is I need to write the prediction of tf model into hdfs file. However I can't find the relative API in tensorflow about how to save data in hdfs file, only find the api about reading hdfs file 
Until now the way I did it is to save the trained tf model into pb file in local and then load the pb file using Java api in spark or Mapreduce code. The problem of both spark or mapreduce is the running speed is very slow and failed with exceeds memory error. 
Here is my demo:

```
public class TF_model implements Serializable{

public Session session;

public TF_model(String model_path){
    try{
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(model_path);
        byte[] graphBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
        graph.importGraphDef(graphBytes);
        this.session = new Session(graph);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("failed to load tensorflow model");
    }
}
// this is the function to predict a sample in hdfs
public int[][] predict(int[] token_id_array){
    Tensor z = session.runner()
            .feed("words_ids_placeholder", Tensor.create(new int[][]{token_id_array}))
            .fetch("softmax_prediction").run().get(0);
    double[][][] softmax_prediction = new double[1][token_id_array.length][2];
    z.copyTo(softmax_prediction);
    return softmax_prediction[0];
}}
```

below is my spark code:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(file_path)
val predct_result= rdd.mapPartitions(pa=>{
    val tf_model = new TF_model("model.pb")
    pa.map(line=>{
      val transformed = transform(line) // omitted the transform code
      val rs = tf_model .predict(transformed)
      rs
    })
  })
```

I also tried tensorflow deployed in hadoop, but can't find a way to write big dataset into HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You may read model file from hdfs one time, then use sc.broadcast your bytes array of your graph to partitions. Finally, start load graph and predict. Just to avoid read file multiple time from hdfs.

Comment: oh, sorry, you load from resources, I looked it wrong. Anyway, thanks for your IOUtils class to help me with bytes stream load problem.

Comment: I used Tensor.close() to fix memory leak problem, and have slow problem too.

Comment: I found it's the cpu limit the whole predict speed, so actually I should pose a question " how to increase the cpu number of each task in a spark application while now the default cpu number is one for each task". Anyway thanks for your answer,